# How to make file paths configurable within an ArcGIS Python Add-In?

Tags: python, python-2.7, add-in, arcgis

This might be a general programming question but since I am doing it from within an Add-In therefore asking here at GIS forum. I have a project folder with sub-folders containing several files on my hard disk which I read from within my Python Add-In, its hard coded e.g.:

```
dem = r'C:/project/raster/dem'
```

and Add-In is in

`r'C:/project/Add-In'`

folder. I tried doing '../raster/dem' to define path of input raster layer but it failed to read. Please suggest how can I make it generic so that if I move project folder to D drive then Add-In would still be able to read data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference materials that are located within the add-in, everything that's included within the 'Install' directory will be copied into the appropriate location within AssemblyCache. You can then reference this by doing something like:

```
local_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.basename(__file__))
raster_path = os.path.join(local_path, 'rasters')
```

And from there, treat `raster_path` as a nomral path.

Comment: Just curious -- So all data files will be located in the AssemblyCache and will be referenced from there? If this is the case, then how is it different from placing files in sub-folders along with AddIn file and referencing them from there?

Comment: This way, when you pacakge up an .esriaddin file to deliver to someone else, it'll also work there. If you're only running things locally and your paths don't change, you can probably just stick with hardcoded paths everywhere, or use `os.path.abspath` first so you can make relative references properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could read in a configuration file stored under the user's profile. Because ArcGIS add-ins overwrite themselves every time the host application is opened, you don't want to store user-specific configuration information inside the add-in itself.

The configuration file can be in any format you want (e.g. XML, plain text), but the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) class makes reading and writing to an [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)-like file format easy.

Comment: Add-in's don't overwrite themselves every time the application is opened, only when the Add-in installation occurs.